# Huge space above footnotes in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote, line-spacing

I can't remove the space above footnotes in Word 2008 without messing up the rest of the spacing in the document. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

The space above the footnotes seems to vary. The solution [here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-ways-remove-extra-spaces-related-footnotes-word-document/), which recommends using a justified vertical alignment in Page Setup, does remove the unwanted space but it completely messes up the spacing in the rest of the document, even when applied only to selected text. I just want the specific footnote fixed and no other spacing to be affected, as there are no other problem areas.

Basically, I want all footnotes to be at the bottom of the page and to have no other space above the separator. Is this possible without having to convert the whole document to a vertical justified format?

Update:
Using the 'fix' suggested does remove the space above footnotes but creates additional space on other parts of the page. For example, hitting Return after a word results in a large space of around 10 lines.

Comment: Check in the Paragraph properties, Line and Page Breaks tab, the check-boxes in the Pagination section for: The last paragraph on the page, the footnote, the first paragraph in the following page.

Comment: The Footnote Separator might have spaces before added to it. To check go into Draft View. The on the Reference tab select Show Notes. From the pull-down, Footnotes menu choose the separator. Place your selection point in the separator. Right-click and open the format Paragraph dialog. Clear any points before setting.

Comment: @harrymc The styles headings have both 'Keep with next' and 'Keep lines together' checked. I think the body of the document has neither checked, but I will have to go through all the text to see if it is causing the issue.

Comment: @RichMichaels I made sure to delete any additional spaces around the footnote separator and that didn't fix it. Although I am not sure what you mean by "clear any points before setting" - could you clarify?

Comment: Paragraphs that have both 'Keep with next' and 'Keep lines together' will "glue" together. If there is not enough space on the page for all the "glued" paragraphs, they will move to a new page. If that's the case for the paragraphs in the next page, it explains the problem.

Comment: Removing Keep with next and Keep lines together has fixed spacing in some areas of the text, but the spacing on pages containing footnotes is still off. I have removed all those checks on paragraphs at the end and beginning of the pages, as well on the footnotes.

Comment: Take a look at MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on Improving the Bottom Line for the settings that can cause this. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BottomLine.htm Aligning the page vertically is definitely NOT the answer.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Great article you linked there! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

From your example, it looks like there is at least a "Space After" setting applied to the Footnote Separator or there is a "Space Before" setting applied to the Footnote Text Style. Either way, it leads me to speculate that there might also be a "Space Before" setting applied to the Footnote Separator.

The only way to check a Footnote Separator is from Draft View. And then click on the Show Notes button on the Reference tab. Doing that you should see something like below.

[image]

Use the Footnotes pull-down menu and select Footnotes Separator. Then Right Click on the bar and choose Paragraph from the contextual menu that displays.

[image]

Check/adjust the Spacing Before and After settings for the Footnote Separator in this dialog where I have highlighted.

[image]

If this is not what is causing the problem, then check the "Keep With Next" settings on the paragraphs on the following page that @harrymc is suggesting.

Comment: There was one instance of a Space After, which I cleared. I then noticed that the body text of the entire document has a 10pt After Spacing. But there are still some irregular spacings being caused by footnotes. Should I remove the 10pt After spacing for the whole document?

Comment: What I have noticed now is that when there is a footnote attached to text on a page, text spacing on the preceding page is irregular. I have cleared the Keep with next and Keep lines together check boxes but the spacing is still irregular.

Comment: No, I wouldn't remove it because 10pt is small and there's a bigger issue here. Have you looked into what @harrymc has suggested?

Comment: Could it be that a Top aligned document simply has some irregular spacing at the bottom of some pages in the document? And that it is unavoidable?

Comment: Is your footnote style linked to your normal style?  Unlink it from any other style and then set the paragraph spacing as you like it.  Also, you should post a sample of your document so that we can inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem (at least in my case) is that I am using section breaks (continuous). These section breaks separate Endnotes and Footnotes from different sections. So if the paragraph after the empty space is using a footnote reference, it is placed on the new page to keep the Endnotes/Footnotes separate from the first page.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/section-break-causes-an-unexpected-page-break-in-word-4bc08567-c7ca-72f5-be3e-022996b39dd6

The Solution posted does not work for me. As of now I only have not found a working solution as listed in the Edit below.

The reason I am using section breaks is so that I can use different headers. It is looking now though as if I should delete the section breaks (and not have 2/3 of an empty page) and not using any headers.

Maybe these Insights will help someone else to find the solution.

Edit: Temporary fix (in the case of using section breaks)

1. Remove section break from the middle of the page.
2. The paragraphs will flow as usual.
3. At the end of the page, seperate paragraphs manually (Enter) and insert the section break here, so that it's at the end of the page.